# Is it OK if my Durock cement board got wet?

Tags: cement, board

I bought some cement board for the bathroom remodel and I stored it in the garage. No idea how but each sheet got a couple wet spots through them. I moved them inside to dry. After they dry are they still usable?

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. Interesting question; let's see if one of our pros has a good answer. And, you should probably [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know how best to participate here.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Durock and similar cement-based products are designed for uses where it may be exposed to water.  It's not waterproof but it will not disintegrate or lose its strength when wet.

You should allow it dry thoroughly, however, before using it.